# I'm having issues setting up the LM13700 as a floating resistor and measuring the correct resistance values

Tags: current-measurement, ota, voltage-controlled-resistor

So I'm still learning how OTA's work, and have an application using the LM13700 as a floating voltage controlled resistor as seen below:

[image: Floating VCR]

I'm using +/-12V rails for this circuit. I have it set up so that I am injecting a 1mA bias current into the Vc/Iabc pin. With the Ra & R values I'm using, I'm expecting to get an Rx of around 500 ohms. But when I build this thing out and measure the resistance between pins 12 and 5 (the outputs), I'm reading on the order of megaohms(2.5 to 3 megaohms to be specific).

Is measuring the resistance of this floating resistor as simple as putting a voltmeter across pins 12 and 5 after you've implemented the circuit as shown above, or am I missing something?

Comment: A DMM on its resistance range won't work. Any DC offsets will confuse it. Infer the resistance by injecting a signal at one end and measuring the output at the other end into a known load (like 500R) ... and swapping ends.

Answer (score 1):

Using a DVM might not do the trick here, especially if it is auto-ranging. I would suggest applying a voltage while measuring the current and then calculating the virtual resistance from there. The problem is that the meter will likely always apply the same injection voltage in all ranges and it will always start in the highest range. If the voltage produces a current that is within the current range, it won't change to the next range and you will always read in the highest range.